# $p$ is odd prime such that $p\equiv 1\mod{3}$ and a is primitive root $\mod{p}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

prove or disprove:

Suppose that p is odd prime such that $p\equiv 1\mod{3}$  and a is primitive root mod $p$. Let $a=r^{\frac{p-1}{3}}$ then $1$, $a$, $a^2$ are solution to $x^3\equiv 1\mod{p}$ that are distinct $\mod{p}$.

I guess it is true statement

since $p$ is odd prime such that $p\equiv 1\mod{3}$ then $p-1+3k$ also, since  a is primitive root $\mod{p}$ then $(a,p)=1$

Let $a=r^{\frac{p-1}{3}}$ so let $a^3=r^{p-1}$

any help with that please how can I conclude that $1$, $a$, $a^2$ are solution to $x^3\equiv1\mod{p}$ that are distinct $\mod{p}$?

Comment: What did you try? What is $r$?

Comment: Do you know that the multiplicative group of nonzero residue classes modulo $p$ is always cyclic?

Comment: @DietrichBurde r is $r^$a_i$=$n_i$   $ where  $n_i$ from 1 to p-1

Answer (score 1):

If $r$ is a primitive root, then $a$ has order $3$ and so generates a subgroup of order $3$. The elements of this subgroup are exactly $1,a,a^2$ and so these are the roots of $x^3=1$. There can be no others because the integers mod $p$ form a field.

Comment: how can I show the solutions are distinct ? thank you

Comment: @dr.rise, $a$ has order $3$.